# Error on POST with Restangular

Tags: java, restangular

I want to send from front end application to back end a POST request with a complex JSON object.

**Back end side**

I have a class named NotificationService and a method named writeNotification as follow:

```
@POST
@Path(SERVICE_PATH_WRITENOTIFICATION)
public Response writeNotification(@FormParam("notification") String notification)
```

**Front end side**

I send this:

```
var obj = [ {
    to : $scope.formComboDestinatari.listaDestinatari,
    subject : $scope.formOggetto,
    date : "xxx",
    body : $scope.formTesto,
    type : $scope.formComboTipologia
} ];
```

If I use this syntax:

```
Restangular.one('serverpath/writenotification').post(obj);
```

When I try to send the request I have this error:

`500 internal server error`

If I use this syntax:

```
Restangular.one('serverpath').post('writenotification', obj);
```

`400 Bad request`

I don't understand where's my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I'm wrong twice.

The first:

the `obj` var mustn't have [ ] because represent an array.

So the definition var becomes:

```
var obj = {
    to : $scope.formComboDestinatari.listaDestinatari,
    subject : $scope.formOggetto,
    date : "xxx",
    body : $scope.formTesto,
    type : $scope.formComboTipologia
};
```

The second:

Instead of Restangular now I use $http in this way:

```
$http({
    url : "pathserver/writenotification",
    method : "POST",
    data : obj,
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
    alert('Notifica inviata');
}).error(function(data) {
    alert('Invio notifica fallito');
});
```